# Implementation of switch case for check box

Tags: java, switch-statement, jcheckbox

Is there any way to implement switch case for checkbox?

Example: I have 4 checkboxes, if I selected 2 checkboxes, how to trigger the case to the output I want?

```
 double exam = 0.0, assign = 0.0, quiz = 0.0, ct = 0.0;

                if (examchkbox.isSelected()) {
                exam = Double.parseDouble(examtextfield.getText());
                }
                if(ctchkbox.isSelected()) {
                ct = Double.parseDouble(cttextfield.getText());    
                }
                if(quizchkbox.isSelected()) {
                quiz = Double.parseDouble(quiztextfield.getText());    
                }
                if(asschkbox.isSelected()) {
                assign = Double.parseDouble(asstextfield.getText());    
                }
                if (!(exam + ct + quiz + assign == 100)) {
                markerrorlbl.setText("Total marks must be 100");
                }
                else {  

                // implementation of code here
                }
```

[image: Design View]
This is the design view.

Let say I ticked **Exam** and **Class Test**, I just want to select the value in the text field and store the marks by using switch case. Is that possible?

This is the thing about I want but I've no idea how to implement with Checkbox.

```
switch(x) 
        {
            case 1 : A = new exam(marks)   ;total+=marks;  break;
            case 2 : A = new test(marks)   ;total+=marks; break;
            case 3 : A = new quiz(marks)   ;total+=marks; break;
            case 4 : A = new assignment(marks) ;total+=marks;break;     
        }
```

Comment: You can use an `if` with an `&` to check the two checkboxes are checked. Why do you want specifically switch?

Comment: whenever an item is checked/unchecked, call your function that counts the number of items checked and add your switch case there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a switch instead of the if statements you already have in your code?

Since you can select the four checkboxes independently from each other, a `switch` is not the best solution here. You have four checkboxes, so there are 2^4 = 16 possible "check patterns":

```
int pattern = (cb1.isSelected() ? 0b0001 : 0)
            | (cb2.isSelected() ? 0b0010 : 0)
            | (cb3.isSelected() ? 0b0100 : 0) 
            | (cb4.isSelected() ? 0b1000 : 0);

switch (pattern) {
    case 0b0001:
        // code for when only checkbox 1 is checked 
        break;
    ...
    case 0b0011:
        // code for when checkbox 1 and checkbox 2 are checked
        break;
    ...
    case 0b1011:
        // code for when only checkbox 1, 2 and 4 are checked
        break;
    ...
}
```

If you use a switch, you would need 16 cases. In contrast, you only need 4 if statements:

```
if (checkbox 1 is checked) {
    // code for when checkbox 1 is checked
}
if (checkbox 2 is checked) {
    // code for when checkbox 2 is checked 
}
...
```

Note that these are 4 independent if statements, no `else if`s there.

Comment: ok now i've figured out what to do, thanks for your advice! :)